# emmeans "consec" contrast method sorting as characters instead of numeric (R)

Tags: r, emmeans

I have a dataset with multiple timepoints, and I would like to contrast time2-time1, time3-time2, etc.

Unfortunately, the time data is being sorted as characters instead of numeric, resulting in 10 being next to 100 instead of 20 and 30.

I tried the following function:

```
lm_Time <- lm(measure ~ time, data = mydata)
lm_Time %>% 
emmeans(consec ~ time, adjust = "dunnettx") %>%
pluck("contrasts") -> TimeContrasts
```

The function works, except it sorts the time column as characters instead of numeric (see below).

| contrast | estimate | SE | df | t.ratio | p.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time10 - time0 | -0.06926 | 0.433 | 186 | -0.160 | 1.0000 |
| time100 - time10 | 0.51698 | 0.433 | 186 | 1.193 | 0.9424 |
| time110 - time100 | -0.23915 | 0.433 | 186 | -0.552 | 0.9995 |
| time120 - time110 | 0.06666 | 0.433 | 186 | 0.154 | 1.0000 |
| time130 - time120 | -0.13622 | 0.433 | 186 | -0.314 | 1.0000 |
| time140 - time130 | 0.09445 | 0.433 | 186 | 0.218 | 1.0000 |
| time150 - time140 | -0.53962 | 0.433 | 186 | -1.245 | 0.9280 |
| time160 - time150 | 0.17560 | 0.433 | 186 | 0.405 | 0.9999 |
| time170 - time160 | -0.45169 | 0.433 | 186 | -1.042 | 0.9726 |
| time180 - time170 | 0.22070 | 0.433 | 186 | 0.509 | 0.9997 |
| time190 - time180 | 0.13796 | 0.433 | 186 | 0.318 | 1.0000 |
| time20 - time190 | 0.19190 | 0.433 | 186 | 0.443 | 0.9999 |
| time200 - time20 | 0.12803 | 0.433 | 186 | 0.295 | 1.0000 |

I have tried applying `as.numeric()` to within the `emmeans`, and I have also tried applying several sort commands within the `emmeans`. Neither of those strategies worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

The dput output is below:

```
structure(list(ID = c("NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7", "NSFA1", "NSFA2", "NSFA3", "NSFA4", "NSFA5", 
"NSFA6", "NSFA7"), time = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "20", "20", "20", "20", 
"20", "20", "20", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "40", 
"40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "50", "50", "50", "50", "50", 
"50", "50", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60", "70", "70", 
"70", "70", "70", "70", "70", "80", "80", "80", "80", "80", "80", 
"80", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "90", "100", "100", 
"100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "110", "110", "110", "110", 
"110", "110", "110", "120", "120", "120", "120", "120", "120", 
"120", "130", "130", "130", "130", "130", "130", "130", "140", 
"140", "140", "140", "140", "140", "140", "150", "150", "150", 
"150", "150", "150", "150", "160", "160", "160", "160", "160", 
"160", "160", "170", "170", "170", "170", "170", "170", "170", 
"180", "180", "180", "180", "180", "180", "180", "190", "190", 
"190", "190", "190", "190", "190", "200", "200", "200", "200", 
"200", "200", "200", "210", "210", "210", "210", "210", "210", 
"210", "220", "220", "220", "220", "220", "220", "220", "230", 
"230", "230", "230", "230", "230", "230", "240", "240", "240", 
"240", "240", "240", "240", "250", "250", "250", "250", "250", 
"250", "250", "260", "260", "260", "260", "260", "260", "260", 
"270", "270", "270", "270", "270", "270", "270", "280", "280", 
"280", "280", "280", "280", "280", "290", "290", "290", "290", 
"290", "290", "290", "300", "300", "300", "300", "300", "300", 
"300"), measure = c(1.63351915308149, 1.77874773175867, 3.50015705563717, 
2.32439624137633, 2.3867235968419, 1.52099769112638, 2.12727500927918, 
1.61164867026043, 1.61792828366444, 3.24946382696031, 2.69591940586543, 
1.48047889731353, 2.6039168403024, 1.52764952726582, 1.3997227977924, 
1.51431737410292, 2.56147122248565, 3.43364864277362, 1.7900436237908, 
2.91196193028045, 1.43887322470176, 1.54086882673671, 0.674879288412828, 
1.67032386923659, 1.32586875843305, 1.55071050734488, 2.50880307626376, 
2.20798510204848, 1.3997227977924, 1.10183991260897, 2.67587406424878, 
1.27976883573895, 1.84265098995821, 3.23205426515144, 1.31065772450765, 
3.12284967113441, 1.78722703100539, 2.34069511686221, 1.11497149593301, 
2.92374654058626, 1.10183991260897, 1.34840317315465, 2.0328425539765, 
2.26187465285822, 2.01575691287562, 1.1366002145544, 2.24481304292639, 
1.12798681094492, 2.05215784403175, 1.64588236163568, 0.788848102703265, 
2.26822947635246, 1.41407494649988, 2.79612264008161, 3.2971566029204, 
1.01114444121153, 2.34272179121274, 0.490670231210412, 3.35547534159059, 
1.56697720910629, 3.76349049652496, 2.27245306481092, 3.34607147916713, 
2.20579393251666, 0.510938075889187, 2.14099529429958, 2.47343216356879, 
1.4632789901381, 1.16214289336498, 0.524281050785507, 2.47343216356879, 
2.65390574185909, 2.74993445860681, 3.06105343797528, 2.01575691287562, 
3.12944787442723, 2.32234810380723, 2.39460639823322, 1.14516360440023, 
3.61354673134165, 3.13339592533708, 1.87769173477054, 2.99718218410231, 
1.57021041547202, 2.80710002416611, 2.80710002416611, 2.32234810380723, 
3.00704177887718, 1.81794375160058, 1.65815005889353, 2.77873927388457, 
2.39263901736138, 1.43887322470176, 2.88066886611877, 3.33425302894405, 
2.88517157922089, 1.9353384954053, 1.37793940174855, 4.06678904685626, 
0.904333783554537, 1.95071681173142, 2.59164010266151, 2.43157405759104, 
3.51860519251912, 1.44238347008031, 2.26399552889217, 0.391759719208298, 
2.64367602470992, 2.34474611154949, 2.24052109566008, 1.02511451256556, 
2.2188991165524, 1.40691564748298, 0.490670231210412, 1.79846414624875, 
2.28715485377053, 2.2913325148839, 3.13339592533708, 2.94999390433702, 
1.59901406500575, 0.46315712473212, 1.63041323278104, 2.18372649783188, 
1.56373733250782, 2.66745615413171, 1.08858972736106, 2.3038053769111, 
0.968404988487708, 2.52348814369453, 1.31447482577578, 2.12037300468822, 
2.62131114755134, 0.889130408216507, 2.45832546944028, 2.43734073503924, 
1.19552867313708, 2.64879810692067, 1.31065772450765, 2.32644196921343, 
1.32964778894198, 3.1646915191577, 2.80710002416611, 2.33460090868772, 
2.30794313445257, 1.44938009456903, 2.48280884261364, 1.3997227977924, 
2.21454184581367, 0.44214095562798, 1.67939356690503, 1.07521853316776, 
1.60849948302688, 3.11490171734115, 2.08072041821122, 2.28924494468403, 
1.36324278630157, 2.26187465285822, 2.0255415025483, 1.80684117645744, 
1.88832438338773, 1.63661899987595, 3.78350083526141, 0.626512719015478, 
2.89712590600148, 2.90900413686774, 2.74185221146685, 1.99601399120726, 
1.65202804664059, 1.70629759508941, 0.420784878794904, 2.82266964479624, 
2.64709235591804, 1.27586287328904, 3.10692062902339, 0.563531228974086, 
1.70333051302107, 0.490670231210412, 3.43477552606197, 1.61479159460257, 
1.67032386923659, 1.7210511443671, 2.09013457393598, 3.57400449218521, 
0.674879288412828, 2.94854531315548, 2.50880307626376, 1.48389609617481, 
2.38078814285196, 1.11497149593301, 1.82346673568208, 2.0924799231334, 
1.2160204292426, 2.65560509195653, 1.96342384608139, 1.58947126851799, 
1.81517521048448, 1.63971279949374, 0.202489271623402, 1.81517521048448, 
2.49585349398409, 2.06411794217993, 1.79285532806874, 0.963576913267833, 
2.80553581934717, 0.141552843569217, 1.90151910036246, 2.5051128068377, 
3.20564340068545, 2.61437354960207, 1.56697720910629, 2.45452855632671, 
1.95581132475685, 1.51431737410292, 1.08414622910813, 1.83719277707321, 
0.821294818608212, 3.13995801105766)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-217L))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please provide a dput() of your data so others can replicate the issue.

Comment: Hi Santiago, thank you. I'm still figuring out my way around, but I think I have correctly added the dput() of my data to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Thomas and welcome to SO!

The `lm()` is coercing the time variable as factor. In order to prevent that, you have to do it yourself prior to fitting the model:

```
> mydata$time <- factor(mydata$time, levels = unique(mydata$time))
> lm_Time <- lm(measure ~ time, data = mydata)
> lm_Time_emmeans <- emmeans(lm_Time, consec ~ time, adjust = "dunnettx")
> 
> lm_Time_emmeans$contrasts
 contrast          estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 time10 - time0     -0.0693 0.433 186  -0.160  1.0000
 time20 - time10     0.0376 0.433 186   0.087  1.0000
 time30 - time20    -0.5101 0.433 186  -1.177  0.9463
 time40 - time30     0.1947 0.433 186   0.449  0.9999
 time50 - time40     0.1282 0.433 186   0.296  1.0000
 time60 - time50    -0.1240 0.433 186  -0.286  1.0000
 time70 - time60     0.0499 0.433 186   0.115  1.0000
 time80 - time70     0.5595 0.433 186   1.291  0.9136
 time90 - time80    -0.9510 0.433 186  -2.195  0.3813
 time100 - time90    1.1321 0.433 186   2.613  0.1688
 time110 - time100  -0.2392 0.433 186  -0.552  0.9995
 time120 - time110   0.0667 0.433 186   0.154  1.0000
 time130 - time120  -0.1362 0.433 186  -0.314  1.0000
 time140 - time130   0.0945 0.433 186   0.218  1.0000
 time150 - time140  -0.5396 0.433 186  -1.245  0.9280
 time160 - time150   0.1756 0.433 186   0.405  0.9999
 time170 - time160  -0.4517 0.433 186  -1.042  0.9726
 time180 - time170   0.2207 0.433 186   0.509  0.9997
 time190 - time180   0.1380 0.433 186   0.318  1.0000
 time200 - time190   0.3199 0.433 186   0.738  0.9967
 time210 - time200  -0.5330 0.433 186  -1.230  0.9324
 time220 - time210   0.1509 0.433 186   0.348  1.0000
 time230 - time220   0.4763 0.433 186   1.099  0.9630
 time240 - time230  -0.5804 0.433 186  -1.340  0.8965
 time250 - time240   0.0260 0.433 186   0.060  1.0000
 time260 - time250   0.2801 0.433 186   0.646  0.9986
 time270 - time260  -0.2186 0.433 186  -0.505  0.9997
 time280 - time270  -0.3117 0.433 186  -0.719  0.9972
 time290 - time280   0.5381 0.433 186   1.242  0.9290
 time300 - time290  -0.2762 0.433 186  -0.637  0.9987

P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 30 tests
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought the problem was coming at the contrast step, but adjusting it earlier fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change the type from character to numeric first:

```
mydata$time <- as.numeric(mydata$time)
```

before running your model?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I've tried, but when I do this, all contrasts are removed and the emmeans doesn't run.

Comment: Sorry to hear about this :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually coding the factor levels, convert `time` to numeic, then treat it as a factor when you model it.

```
> mydata = transform(mydata, time = as.numeric(time))
> lm_Time <- lm(measure ~ factor(time), data = mydata)
> EMM = emmeans(lm_Time, "time")
> contrast(EMM, "consec")
 contrast          estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 time10 - time0     -0.0693 0.433 186  -0.160  1.0000
 time20 - time10     0.0376 0.433 186   0.087  1.0000
 time30 - time20    -0.5101 0.433 186  -1.177  0.9984
 time40 - time30     0.1947 0.433 186   0.449  1.0000
 time50 - time40     0.1282 0.433 186   0.296  1.0000
 time60 - time50    -0.1240 0.433 186  -0.286  1.0000
 time70 - time60     0.0499 0.433 186   0.115  1.0000
 time80 - time70     0.5595 0.433 186   1.291  0.9944
 time90 - time80    -0.9510 0.433 186  -2.195  0.5339
 time100 - time90    1.1321 0.433 186   2.613  0.2307
 time110 - time100  -0.2392 0.433 186  -0.552  1.0000
 time120 - time110   0.0667 0.433 186   0.154  1.0000
 time130 - time120  -0.1362 0.433 186  -0.314  1.0000
 time140 - time130   0.0945 0.433 186   0.218  1.0000
 time150 - time140  -0.5396 0.433 186  -1.245  0.9965
 time160 - time150   0.1756 0.433 186   0.405  1.0000
 time170 - time160  -0.4517 0.433 186  -1.042  0.9997
 time180 - time170   0.2207 0.433 186   0.509  1.0000
 time190 - time180   0.1380 0.433 186   0.318  1.0000
 time200 - time190   0.3199 0.433 186   0.738  1.0000
 time210 - time200  -0.5330 0.433 186  -1.230  0.9971
 time220 - time210   0.1509 0.433 186   0.348  1.0000
 time230 - time220   0.4763 0.433 186   1.099  0.9994
 time240 - time230  -0.5804 0.433 186  -1.340  0.9913
 time250 - time240   0.0260 0.433 186   0.060  1.0000
 time260 - time250   0.2801 0.433 186   0.646  1.0000
 time270 - time260  -0.2186 0.433 186  -0.505  1.0000
 time280 - time270  -0.3117 0.433 186  -0.719  1.0000
 time290 - time280   0.5381 0.433 186   1.242  0.9967
 time300 - time290  -0.2762 0.433 186  -0.637  1.0000

P value adjustment: mvt method for 30 tests
```